# Strange behavior of the na.kalman function from the R imputeTS package

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, imputation, imputets

I am experimenting with functions from the `imputeTS` package. This package provides several functions to impute missing values in univariate time series data. I tested them and they all great, except the `na_kalman` function. This function changes the original numeric vector. Below is an example.

```
# Load packages
library(imputeTS)

# Set seeds
set.seed(123)

# Generate 10 random number
dat <- rnorm(10)

# Replace the first 10 numbers to be NA
dat[1:5] <- NA

# Check the numbers in dat
dat
 [1]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.6868529
[10] -0.4456620
```

As you can see, I created a vector with 10 numbers while the first 5 are `NA`.

```
# Apply the na_kalman function
dat2 <- na_kalman(dat)

# Check the numbers in dat2
dat2
[1]  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.6868529
[10] -0.4456620

# Check the numbers in dat again
dat
     [1]  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.6868529
[10] -0.4456620
```

It seems like the `dat2` shows the `na_kalman` function successfully imputed the `NA`. However, the original vector, `dat`, was also changed. This is a behavior I want to avoid. I would like to know if there is a way to ask `na_kalman` not to change the original vector.

**Note**

1. When I changed the vector length to a large number, such as `rnorm(1000)`, I notice that all the missing values in `dat` will be changed to the first non-missing values in the original data. It seems like `dat` is not simply a copy of `dat2` after the `na_kalman` function.
2. I also tested other functions from the `imputeTS` package, such as `na_interpolation`, `na_locf`, `na_mean`. They don't have this behavior. `dat` remains to be the same vector after running those function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of imputeTS package here. Thanks for your e-mail.

This is indeed no feature...it is rather a small bug.
I directly fixed this bug.

> Update: New Version with fix also on CRAN now. Fixed with version 3.0. Just
>   update the imputeTS package, if you encounter this bug.

Unfortunately I uploaded a new package version on CRAN just hours before you wrote me. Otherwise it would have been already included in the 2.1 update.
I will make a update with the bugfix included by the end of the week.

If you need a fixed version meanwhile, you can install the new version directly from github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("SteffenMoritz/imputeTS")
```

For the ones interested what the problem was:

It was a problem with C++ Code I call via Rcpp.
I forgot to make a deep copy of an object.